# .Thumbdata3 file extraction. TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, file, extract

I'm aware there are similar threads and I've gone through them, but they didn't help my case:

A while ago I saved two .thumbdata3 files that are about 500mb in size each. [This stackexchange thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58087/read-content-of-thumbdata-file) claimed I could extract small jpegs from the files using a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""extract files from Android thumbdata3 file"""

f=open('thumbdata3.dat','rb')
tdata = f.read()
f.close()

ss = '\xff\xd8'
se = '\xff\xd9'

count = 0
start = 0
while True:
    x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
    if x1 < 0:
        break
    x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
    jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
    count += 1
    fname = 'extracted%d03.jpg' % (count)
    fw = open(fname,'wb')
    fw.write(jpg)
    fw.close()
    start = x2+2
```

However it returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "... extract.py", line 15, in <module>
    x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

After searching around I thought the error might be between using 2.7 and 3.5 methodology, and changed the **'rb'** in the f.open function to **'r'** only to get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Thumbdata\thumbadata extract.py", line 6, in <module>
    tdata = f.read()
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 277960004: character maps to <undefined>
```

It's worth mentioning that the script and the file are both in the same folder. I'm using Atom with a Python run package, as well as Anaconda3.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must keep using **rb** mode for read binary in **f=open('thumbdata3.dat','rb')** to read that binary data.

The problem is that **f** is a binary stream then **find** function expect a parameter of byte type, which is new in Python3.

**ss** and **se** were assigned as string value, so its type is string (I guess **ss** and **se** stand for string start and string end).

You need to encode those strings to binary type using **encode()** function:

```
x1 = tdata.find(ss.encode(),start)

x2 = tdata.find(se.encode(),x1)
```

Please test and comment the output to ensure it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Just **keep the same code !**

This error  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "... extract.py", line 15, in <module>
    x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

is due to the using of strings instead of byte-like object here :

```
ss = '\xff\xd8'
se = '\xff\xd9'
```

And to fix this problem just add a **b** before those strings
this is the solution :

```
ss = b'\xff\xd8'
se = b'\xff\xd9'
```